# Andengine importing error

Tags: android, eclipse, andengine

I try integrate AndEngine Library to my project I download Lib from [AndEngine](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich) , and download some extension but I find problem with multi-touch

this problem I find this importing
import org.anddev.andengine.util.SystemUtils;

I search and I find the soluation 
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48427/cant-set-up-andengine-gles2-anchorcenter-examples-extensions

I try it and it solve my problem

but I still have some problems in some imports

```
import org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.controller.BaseTouchController;
 import org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent;
 import org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.detector.BaseDetector;
```

what I missing , any one can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These imports are for AndEngine-GLES1, you have to use the new packages (org.andengine)

Comment: I have project that use old version , How can I find the old one ? or how can I update my project

Comment: The github repo has the old version, just switch to the 'master' branch. Altough I suggest to upgrade your projects at least to the GLES-2 version.